# $B\subseteq A \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ closed, then any continuous $f:B\to \partial [0,1]^2$ admits an extension

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

*Prove or refute*:

> Let $A$ be a closed subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$, for some $n$, and $B$ be a closed subset of $A$. Then any continuous function $f:B\to \partial[0,1]^2$, where $\partial[0,1]^2$ is the boundary of the unit square in $\mathbb{R}^2$, has an extension to a continuous function $F:A \to[0,1]^2$.

I'm not sure yet if that's true. However, I haven't found any counter-example.

I think we should identify the boundary with the circle and somehow use algebraic topology to get a contradiction.
I have also Tietze extension theorem in mind, but I doubt it helps.

Comment: Take $B$ to be $S^1$ and $A=D^2$ and instead of the boundary of the square take $S^1$ again. Then the existence of such a map would give you a retraction from $D^2$ to $S^1$...

Comment: @Spotty How are you constructing the retraction? If we identify $[0, 1]^2$ as $D^2$, then $F$ would be the identity map.

Comment: @fermesomme totally misread the question I thought the extension had the same target as the starting map.

Comment: Unfortunately, a common mistake

Comment: Can you use the Tietze's extension theorem to extend $f$ to a map $F:A\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$, then use the "square projection" retraction $\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow [0,1]^2$?  (This argument doesn't use the fact that the image of $f$ is a subset of $\partial[0,1]^2$, so I am probably missing something obvious.)

Comment: I'm not sure about the first extension. What version of Tietze theorem do you use?

Comment: @ShirlyGeffen [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tietze_extension_theorem) is a Wikipedia link for Teitze extension for functions $f\colon A \rightarrow \mathbb R$. You can use this to obtain an generalization for $f\colon A \rightarrow \mathbb R^n$.

Comment: Oh, I understand what you mean. That looks fine to me. Thanks!